# i am trying to make admin and login page

Tags: php, mysql

this is my database:-lecturer table:-members

```
username   password   status
admin      admin        1
user       user         0
```

this is my `checklogin.php`

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <?php
            ob_start();
            $host="localhost"; // Host name
            $username="root"; // Mysql username
            $password="password"; // Mysql password
            $db_name="lecturer"; // Database name
            $tbl_name="members"; // Table name

            // Connect to server and select databse.
            mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            // Define $myusername and $mypassword
            $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
            $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

            // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
            $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
            $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
            $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
            $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

            $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' and status='1'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

            // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
            if($count==1) {

                // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
                $_session["myusername"] = "myusername";
                $_session["mypassword"] = "mypassword";
                $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                if($info['status'] == 1) {
                    header("location:webpage.php");
                } else
                    header("location:lecturer.php");
            } else {
                echo "Wrong Username or Password";
            }
            ob_end_flush();
        ?>

        <th><a href="main_login.php?pressed=back">Back</a></th>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

what i am trying to is when the system check 
the status is '1' if will lead to `webpage.php` which is admin and 
if the status is '0' it will lead to `lecturer.php` which is user

but when i enter admin and user it kept entering webpage.php

the problem is when i enter user it still lead to webpage.php i wanted it to redirect it to `lecturer.php`

can anybody state what is the mistake that i have done 
thank you very much

Comment: check $info do you have status=0 for user?

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions for database access.  They're deprecated in PHP 5 (because they've not been updated since mysql 4 and are not guaranteed to work properly with mysql 5 or later) and were entirely removed in PHP 7.  Your code will cease to function in modern PHP versions.  Please switch to mysqli or PDO

Comment: Also stripslashes should not be required because magic quotes has long since been removed from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to perform action according to you status remove checking in query `status=1` and also use Limit 1 when you know that there will be only one row can be fetch. it will reduce your processing time as well when your large no of records in table.

So use the code as below

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="lecturer"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1 ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_session["myusername"] = "myusername";
$_session["mypassword"] = "mypassword";
$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($info['status'] == 1){
    header("location:webpage.php");
    exit;
}
else
    header("location:lecturer.php");
    exit;
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}

ob_end_flush();
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <table>
<th><a href="main_login.php?pressed=back">Back</a></th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Remember : User exit if you transfering to another page using header 'loacation'. after call this.

Answer (score 1):

try this.... remove the and status='1' from your query, only pass the parameters with Username and Password when getting result from query then check from status is login user is ADMIN or User then proceed.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="lecturer"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_session["myusername"] = "myusername";
$_session["mypassword"] = "mypassword";
$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($info['status'] === 1){
    header("location:webpage.php");
}
else
    header("location:lecturer.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}

ob_end_flush();
?>

<th><a href="main_login.php?pressed=back">Back</a></th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking status in query itself as `status = 1`. Then it always return the result with status = 1. So you will be redirected to webpage.php.

**Remove condition status = '1' in your query.**